# How to generate clustered standard errors in SJplot package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I'm tiring to plot the output of a model using the `sjPlot` package. I want the standard errors on the plot to reflect the clustered standard errors I'm using in my model. I was wondering what the appropriate call for the `plot_model` function is if I want to cluster my standard errors on `c` in the plot of the predicted values?

```
set.seed(1999)

c <- sample(c("A","B", "C", "D"), size = 100, replace = T)
w <- sample(1:100, size = 100, replace = T)
x <- sample(1:100, size = 100, replace = T)
y <- sample(1:100, size = 100, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(x,y,w,c)

Results <- lm(y ~ x*w, data = df)

library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

plot_model(Results, type = "pred", terms = c("x","w"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clustered" in this case?  Clustered by what?

Comment: Updated the question to reflect your question. I want to cluster my standard errors on `c`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `se=TRUE` to see the standard error as error bars. Unfortunately, this only works for `plot_model`, not for `plot_models` (several models in one graph).